# C# ToList inside LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm working with LINQ and I wonder what's the difference between the two codes below. The result seems same but does using `ToList()` inside the query like `student1` makes one more access to Database?

```cs
var students1 = (from stud in dbContext.Students.Where(s => s.LastName == "Doe").ToList()
               join class in dbContext.Classes
               on ...).ToList();

var students2 = (from stud in dbContext.Students.Where(s => s.LastName == "Doe")
               join class in dbContext.Classes
               on ...).ToList();
```

Comment: When you write a Linq query, you write an "expression". When you call the `.ToList()` method. The expression will be compiled to an actual SQL query and executed on the database.
So in the second case the join will be performed on the sql database. in the first case this will be done in memory.

Answer (score 0):

ToList materializes the query. Note that when accessing the database you are working with IQueryable and your join and where clauses get passed to the database. If you materialize the queryable by calling ToList the database does not process the join but you join the inmemory data with LinqToObjects instead of with LinqToSql.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL is a facility for managing and accessing relational data as objects.

1. It connects to a database, converts LINQ constructs into SQL
2. submits the SQL
3. transforms results into objects
4. Even tracks changes and automatically requests database updates